# Crystal Report - Add a page(without any footer or header) with text at the end of report

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to add a page(Term and Condition page) at the end of crystal report.

The crystal report is for purchase order and at the end of report I want to have a new page with term and conditions.

The "Term and Condition" page should come with out any header or footer.

I have suppress page footer in term and condition page but still it considers the space of the page footer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the issue here? supress `page footer` or write terms and conditions at the end of report?

Answer (score 0):

Add your text to a text object that is located in the `report footer` section.  Set the section's `force new page before` setting to `true`.